# подключение .js и .css на определенную страницу Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно подключить сторонний .css и .js файл на определенную страницу Wordpress? Я пробовал внедрить в тему используя

```
<?php function wpb_adding_scripts() { wp_register_script('coverflow', plugins_url('coverflow.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.1', true); wp_enqueue_script('coverflow'); } add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' ); ?>
```

в functions.php темы

но после изменения я получаю 500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php if (is_front_page() === true): ?>
<script src="http://"></script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Вставляем в шаблон заголовка. `is_front_page()` означает выполнение кода только на домашней странице. Подставляйте любую другую функцию.

Answer (score -1):

Обрати внимание на условный тег [is_page()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/is_page) `WP 1.5`

*Проверяет отображается ли страница "постоянной страницы". Можно указать ID, ярлык или заголовок страницы для проверки. Условный тег.*

Возвращает `true/false`. true, если отображается тип страницы: постоянной страницы и false, если отображается любой другой тип страницы.

```
if( is_page( $page ) ){
     //код
}
```